# Проблема с переносом проекта laravel+vueJS на хостинг

Tags: laravel, vue.js, хостинг, vite

Прошу помощи, перепробовал всё, что нашёл в интернете, но видимо где-то допускаю ошибку. Первый раз заливаю на хостинг VueJS'ный сайт.
Laravel 9 + VueJS (используется vite). На домашнем пк всё отлично, переношу на хостинг - с частью на laravel всё отлично (немного .htaccess пришлось поправить и asset), а вот с VueJS беда.

Сначала опишу основные моменты кода.
В blade.php используется  `@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])`

В .env `APP_URL=https://сайт.ru`

В vite.config.js

```
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import path from 'path'
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

export default defineConfig({       
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        laravel([
            'resources/css/app.css',
            'resources/js/app.js',
        ]),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap'),
        }
    },
```

В packaje.json

```
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite --host",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
        "axios": "^1.3.4",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.1",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.4",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "sass": "^1.32.11",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@vitejs/plugin-basic-ssl": "^1.0.1",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
        "vue": "^3.2.36",
        "vue-loader": "^17.0.1",
        "vue-router": "^4.1.6"
    }
}
```

В .htaccess

```
 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) $1 [L]
 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) /public/$1 [L]
 
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/ [QSA,L]
```

Запускаю npm run dev,

```
  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: http://88.212.236.252:5173/
  *и ещё 8 ip-шек с этим портом*

  LARAVEL v9.48.0  plugin v0.7.4

  ➜  APP_URL: https://сайт.ru/
```

Захожу на сайт, получаю 3 подобных ошибки:

```
 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://сайт.ru/posts/1' was loaded over HTTPS, 
but requested an insecure script 'http://[::]:5173/resources/js/app.js'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Проблемы с файлами :5173/@vite/client , :5173/resources/css/app.css, :5173/resources/js/app.js.

Добавляю в vite.config.js это

```
        host: '127.0.0.1',  
    },
```

Никаких изменений

Меняю в vite.config.js это

```
server: {
        https: true,
        hmr : {
            host: 'сайт.ru'
        },

    },
```

Получаю спустя 50 секунд 3 ошибки тех же файлов, но уже с RR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.
Добавляю port: 3000 (а также всевозможные 3001, 5147)
Пробую поменять host на адрес хостинга- 83.219.286.277 - также ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

Меняю на

```
  server: {
    hmr: {
        host: 'localhost',
    },
  },
```

Получаю

```
client.ts:48 [vite] failed to connect to websocket.
your current setup:
  (browser) localhost:5173/ <--[HTTP]--> localhost:5173/ (server)
  (browser) localhost:5173/ <--[WebSocket (failing)]--> localhost:5173/ (server)
Check out your Vite / network configuration and https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-hmr .
```

Если вручную меняю в public/hot после этого порт на :443 , то GET ```
http://localhost:443/resources/css/app.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (npm run build запускал..)

````
Если вручную меняю в public/hot на https://сайт.ru:443 , то
``` GET https://сайт.ru/@vite/client net::ERR_ABORTED 404
2:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
````

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies

Comment: Добавил доверие ко всем прокси - результат всё тот же (во всех описанных мною вариантах)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решён. Верным ответом были настройки

server: {
https: true,
hmr: {
host: 'сайт.ru',
},
},

И нужно было изменить в файле .env APP_URL=https://сайт.ru/ на APP_URL=https://сайт.ru
Может, конечно, и прокси дополнительно помог, я не знаю, но спасибо, вопрос решён.